# How to Add An External Image to A Github post

Tags: github

I want to add an image which is hosted on an external source to Github, but I see only link when I confirm it to be posted.

`![Image](https://ibb.co/kOnOrb)`

I use this format but it does not work. I click on the link that is created and I see the message `Non-Image content-type returned`.

Comment: can you tell, how you are trying to upload the image and where it on github?

Comment: Uploaded on another site and got the link to the image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was, the link you provided wasn't the image itself. It was the link to a website that contained the image.
By clicking on the image and copying the adress of the image you get the url of the actual image.

This should work for you:

```
![Image](https://image.ibb.co/g0SdPw/Screenshot_from_2018_01_05_11_14_40.png)
```