# Add an image to Github Readme file

Tags: github, readme

I am trying to add an image to a Github ReadmE file and have found the same answers several times on different places, the only thing is that it doesn't work for me. I tried 2 methods, first is to upload to a site and add it to Readme like this:

```
![Image](https://pasteboard.co/JAJAuBP.png)
```

Which is the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109363/how-to-add-an-external-image-to-a-github-post). However, this just gives me this as result, where the link doesn't even go to my picture:

[image]

I also tried the method of putting the picture in a github folder in my project as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/how-to-add-images-to-readme-md-on-github), like this:

```
![alt text](https://github.com/eligolf/affinity_chess/tree/main/imgs/gui_image.png?raw=true)
```

By clicking the link I do get to the folder where my image is located, but the image itself won't show in the Readme. It just shows the same broken image icon as the first method. Removing the `?raw=true` had no effect.

Why is this so hard? Can someone please let me know how to add an image to Github.

Comment: It's because the image "link" you've posted is _not_ the actual image, but a website _containing_ the image, where the actual image is a [blob URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Add An External Image to A Github post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109363/how-to-add-an-external-image-to-a-github-post)

Comment: @Edric, it doesn't really, it wasn't as easy as that. The image got to the URL "https://ibb.co/dr5z1yz". I had to go down to the bottom of the page that opens and click to HTML and pick the link from there. Now it works though, thank you :)